# how to exit python execfile() with out exiting whole script

Tags: python, execfile

I have a code which runs mutile python codes such as below:

```
execfile("1.py")
execfile("2.py")
execfile("3.py")
```

however occasionally one of the above codes as an error, i put `exit('error')` in the code to cancell if there is an error. However i want the rest of the code to run and `exit('error')` exits the whole code, not just the execfile. How do i get the execfile to stop but the others to keep running?

The part of 1.py with exit() is:

```
try :
    Ntot=10000
    x,y,s=myMCMC2D(Ntot,0.78,0.63,1,1)
except :
    exit('error')
```

Comment: This reminds me of the old joke. "doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Well, then, stop doing that". If you don't want your programs to exit when they encounter an error, then don't call `exit` in the except clause in your programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    execfile('1.py')
except SystemExit:
    print "1.py exited"
```

Exit is an exception which can be caught.

Comment: Actually `exit()` is function that raises a `SystemExit` exception when called.